# JQuery Array , 1 issues

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
for (i = 0, j = menuButtonArray.length; i < j; i += 1){
$(menuButtonArray[i]).find("img").attr('src', 'menuImages/'+heavanArray[i]) 
console.log("LOOP = "+i);
}
```

I am swaping out 9 images. Why doesn't the loop update the array element selector each time. It only works on first loop [0] but will not update, while console log does update.

Comment: You haven't initialised any of the arrays

Comment: The `fadeOut` call back runs when the fadeOut has completed which is *after* the loop has completed.

Comment: Thanks. I remedied that. I am still having the simple problem that it is not recognizing  with the i variable: arrayItem[i] . But if I pot in a real number